# Как добавить свой sublayer в Yandex MapKit для android

Tags: android, kotlin, yandexmapkit

Как добавить свой sublayer и добавить на него например polygon, а на другой sublayer placemark?

В примере mapkit-android-demo есть для Placemark:

```java
Integer mapObjectPlacemarkSublayerIndex =
                sublayerManager.findFirstOf(LayerIds.getBuildingsLayerId(), SublayerFeatureType.PLACEMARKS);
```

А как сделать тоже самое для polygon?

```java
        Integer mapObjectPolygonSublayerIndex =
                sublayerManager.findFirstOf(LayerIds.???, SublayerFeatureType.???);
```

Comment: А какова суть задачи в целом? Куда должны попасть подслои? Что должно чем перекрываться? Почему в принципе не можете обойтись без использования sublayerManager?

Comment: @YaCor' да я уже сделал по другому, мне надо было точечный объект перемещать при клике, при этом не трогая закрашенные зоны. Моя идея была в том, чтобы стирать подслой с пользовательской отметкой и рисовать отметку в новом месте. В итоге я нашёл метод перемещения placemark. Вопрос оставил потому что подумал, что было бы интересно узнать есть ли такая возможность?